# Find the number of same consecutive letters in a cell

Tags: excel

I have a cell that contains:

DA - 7200A blankblankblank Dalton Karaoke box

Weight blankblank 10.2kg

Now I've been trying to find a way to substitute all those blank into ": " but got no result. Because the number of blanks in each line is different so I was thinking of how to find the number of blank standing next to each other and then substitute them with ": ".

That's what I thought but I couldn't write a formula for this.

Comment: No, I didn't. How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [substitute](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) function to replace the first double blank   with colon-blank `:`, then use the [trim](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9) function to remove leading spaces, trailing spaces, and collapse multiple spaces to single.